Was becoming a Dasa voluntarily and could they leave their masters?
The buying and selling of servants were mentioned in Mahabharta and Ramayana, but some people have also stated that becoming a Dasa was voluntary. My question is was Dasahood forced upon people or was it voluntary with the nature of the work being that they stay on the premises and the employer may gamble their services to another employer? Please use traditional sources which directly address the topic at hand regarding the law and isn't something tangential or indirect. Feel free to use various Dharmashastras, sutras, and other legal works by religious scholars. Commentaries may also help.

Yajnavalkyasmrti discusses about the slave trade. Among many conditions, it describes debt bondage i.e selling one's own self to the creditor due to inability to repay debt & being captured by the enemy during wartime as means of enslavement. Most notably, it states that if a person unable to feed oneself in times of natural calamnities, manages to sustains himself on food provided by somebody else, then he is bound to be enslaved by his annadata. It also says that if somebody voluntarily submitted himself to somebody else, then he becomes the slave of the person to whom he submitted.

@অনু interesting and what of release?

@অনু as per the Vivasa Chintamani it states a "slave" which is an inaccurate term seems more to be like a serf. Their superior provides them the shelter and they work. I am curious though would freedom be permissible?

Regarding release, I guess that it depended on the sweet will of the master. Manusmrti caricatures all sudras to be enslaved people by default, so it frowns upon releasing sudras from enslavement, stating that being enslaved is inherent to the sudra, so it is of no use freeing them.

Serfdom is a bit different from slavery, in that serfs in the Hindu notion is called the Praja, who payed taxes, while the slaves or dasa didn't.

@অনু true, but a dasa was gotten due to needing to pay debts and they still worked for wages so not a slave.

Since the term for both enslaved people & those who work in exchange of wages in Sanskrit is dasa, I understand your confusion. Outraging the modesty of the enslaved woman is tolerated, but not of the contractual labourer, for then it became parastri-gamana.

@অনু what how is that at all righteous?

@অনু also Medhaiti clearly states that a Shudra and a dasa differ greatly the former being allowed to choose his wages at will the latter being constraint to the boundaries of the workplace.

@অনু also doesn't Manu prohibit the speaking with a dasa in private?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
